# where clause using OR and AND in sqlite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, where-clause

I want to match string to any 3 column of the table and 4th column must be equal to some string in the SQlite Database table. For example , lets take 3 columns : first_name,middle_name,last_name either of these columns equal to = "String" and 4th column : age= 20.But below query reruns "null", So please help to solve the problem.

```
   Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ONE, new String[] { KEY_FNAME, KEY_MNAME, KEY_LNAME }, KEY_FNAME + "=? OR " + KEY_MNAME + "=? OR " + KEY_LNAME + "=?  AND " + KEY_AGE + "=?",
            new String[] { string , string, string, "20"}, null, null, null, null);
```

EDIT :
I also tried with raw query , but not working :

```
  String query = "SELECT * FROM table_one WHERE (" +
            "fname = '"+string1+"' OR mname = '"+string1+"' OR  lname = '"+string1+"') AND age ='20'";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
```

Comment: Used rawQuery for that....

Comment: `new String[] { "string" , "string", "string", "20"}` did you mean like this?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira yes.. whats wrong?

Comment: in the example you put it like this `new String[] { string , string, string, "20"}`

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira those string values are not static its a dynamic

Comment: owh i see.. sorry. did you already try it with execSQL method? rawQuery

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira edited my question , please check

Comment: while creating the database KEY_AGE how you declared- Integer or varchar

Comment: put parentheses for each OR. `WHERE (((" +
            "fname = '"+string1+"' OR mname = '"+string1+")' OR  lname = '"+string1+"'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the OR statements in parentheses:

```
"(" + KEY_FNAME + "=? OR " + KEY_MNAME + "=? OR " + KEY_LNAME + "=?)  AND " + KEY_AGE + "=?"
```

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 `KEY_AGE` might be an integer. Instead of using a placeholder `?`, place the exact value and try again. Of course also remove `"20"` from the string array (next argument).

Comment: All are string. If i use only AND operations it works perfectly. But not with OR